# Is the syntax for LINQ correct to return the duration

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on LINQ where I have a compile-time error and I am unable to pinpoint my mistake.

```
 return string.IsNullOrEmpty(allSongsDuration) ?
        new TimeSpan() :
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(
            allSongsDuration.Split(",")
            .Select(songDurationAsString => TimeSpan.ParseExact(
                songDurationAsString, @"m\:ss", null))
                .Sum(timespan => timespan.TotalSeconds));
```

Above is my code which returns the error: "can not convert from 'string' to 'char'" at the line allSongsDuration.Split(",").

I am using VS 2017. Is there a version-related issue with this syntax? I am trying to split the allSongsDuration as it is separated by commas.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0, there is no overload that takes just a `string`

Comment: What version of .NET are you compiling your code against? Older versions didn't have a `Split` method that took a string alone. You could either pass a `char`, or a `string` AND a `StringSplitOptions`.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, but this one has a default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions), though the default didn't exist in older versions.

Comment: okay. Any option to edit this code to make it work?

Comment: Yeah, pass a `char` not a string, or pass a `StringSplitOptions` after your ",". [.NET Framework docs for string + options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#system-string-split(system-string()-system-stringsplitoptions)), and [.NET Framework docs for char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#system-string-split(system-char())).

Comment: Hi DiplomacyNotWar, I am using VS 2017.

Comment: @Kel Visual Studio is an IDE. I asked you what version of .NET you're compiling your code against. VS 2017 supports .NET Framework (versions 3.5 - 4.7) and .NET Core (versions 1.0 - 2.0). Your code would compile fine with .NET Core 2.0 ([documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-2.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions))) but not with .NET Framework 4.7 ([documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7#system-string-split(system-string()-system-stringsplitoptions))).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double quotes around the character you are passing to `string.Split` which makes it a string, but the single parameter overload requires a `char` instead which means you need to use single quotes:

`allSongsDuration.Split(',')`

Alternatively, you can still pass a string (with double quotes) by specifying the `StringSpltOptions` parameter as well:

`allSongsDuration.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.None)`